# Uploading file to a specific folder with Box api- Objective-c iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, box-api

I can successfuly upload files to root of box storage using the "`fileUploadRequestToFolderWithID:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot` " key but I would like to upload file to a specific folder that I've created using :

```
BOXContentClient *contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];
BOXFolderCreateRequest *folderCreateRequest = [contentClient folderCreateRequestWithName:@"New Folder" parentFolderID:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot];
[folderCreateRequest performRequestWithCompletion:^(BOXFolder *folder, NSError *error) {
    // If successful, folder will be non-nil and represent the newly created folder on Box; otherwise, error will be non-nil.
}];
```

How could I retrieve the folder ID for uploading file to it ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Box iOS SDK refers to the folder's ID as the folder's modelID. You can access the modelID property of the folder within the completion block of folderCreateRequest. For example:

```
BOXContentClient *contentClient = [BOXContentClient defaultClient];
BOXFolderCreateRequest *folderCreateRequest = [contentClient folderCreateRequestWithName:@"New Folder" parentFolderID:BoxAPIFolderIDRoot];
[folderCreateRequest performRequestWithCompletion:^(BOXFolder *folder, NSError *error) {
NSString *folderID = folder.modelID;
}];
```